# Using a getter for my ArrayList doesn't seem to return the values

Tags: java, arraylist, getter-setter

I have two classes where one class contains an ArrayList with items added to the cart and another class that prints the items from the cart. Since the ArrayList is private, I used a getter to get the products from the ArrayList and to print them in the GUI class, yet it returns nothing.

My implementation so far is,CartGUI.java

```
public void printCart() {
        ShoppingCart shoppingCart = new ShoppingCart();
        System.out.println("Products in cart: ");
        for (Product p : shoppingCart.getCart()) {
            System.out.println(p.getProductName());
        }
    }
```

ShoppingCart.java

```
private ArrayList<Product> cart = new ArrayList<>();

public ArrayList<Product> getCart() { return cart; }
```

I tested to see if the ArrayList was empty, but it wasn't.
If the ArrayList is set as static, my code seems to work, but that's not the requirement.

<strike>I thought using a Singleton would fix this issue, but that did not work as well.</strike>

Edit:
I was able to solve this by using a Singleton and passing the same instance of the ShoppingCart to the CartGUI.

Comment: When you do `new ShoppingCart()`, you're creating a _new_ instance of a `ShoppingCart` object each time. So each time, you've created a new, empty cart, and then have nothing to iterate.

Comment: It looks like you simply haven't added anything to the cart yet. It is empty. You should post a minimal runnable example, not just 2 bits of code. Otherwise we can just guess.

Comment: @JayC667 So the way my app works right now is, I add a product to the ShoppingCart, and it gets stored in the cart ArrayList. My issue comes from when I try to access that ArrayList, but it returns nothing.

Comment: @Jr.Macking you are not accessing the same ShoppingCart. As mentioned above, you are creating a new instance of ShoppingCart when `new ShoppingCart()` which is empty. Also when array is set as static,  the same array is shared to all instances. But the problem with that is, ShoppingCart for someone else will have same item in it,

Comment: can you add more code as to where `printCart()` is called from?

Answer (score 1):

In your `PrintCart()` method, your ShoppingCart object is instantiated with a cart that has an empty ArrayList of products. You need to fill up that cart with a setter before you start looping through it.

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this.  Whether `ShoppingCart` is static or not, this will work. Just pass the `ShoppingCart` instance to the method.

```
public <T> static void printCart(ShoppingCart shoppingCart) {
        System.out.println("Products in cart: ");
        for (Product p : shoppingCart.getCart()) {
            System.out.println(p.getProductName());
        }
}
```

But it doesn't make much sense to have `getCart()` method in a `ShoppingCart` class.  `getItems()` or `getProducts()` might make more sense.

or include the `printCart` method in the `ShoppingCart` class as follows:

```
class ShoppingCart {
     private List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();
     public void add(Product) {
           products.add(Product);
     }
     public List<Product> getProducts () {
           return new ArrayList<>(products); //defensive copy
     }
     public void printCart() {
           System.out.println("Products in cart: ");
           for (Product p : products) {
                 System.out.println(p.getProductName());
           }
     }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I followed a similar approach using a getInstance() and was able to fix it. Thank you.

Comment: @Jr.Macking note that the approach you've laid out means there can only ever be 1 shopping cart shared between every user of your application.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're creating a new cart each time in printCart(). Better to use the existing cart or pass it to the GUI class.
in CartGUI.java, pass the existing ShoppingCart instance to the printCart method.

```
     public void printCart(ShoppingCart shoppingCart) {
            System.out.println("Products in cart: ");
            for (Product p : shoppingCart.getCart()) {
                System.out.println(p.getProductName());
            }
        }

// I'm an aspiring Java developer keen on enhancing my coding skills and ensuring robust code practices.
// Feel free to provide suggestions or improvements. Thank you!
```

And after doing so pass the existing ShoppingCart's object when you call printCart method in CartGUI.

```
 ShoppingCart shoppingCart = new ShoppingCart();
 // Add items to the cart
 CartGUI cartGUI = new CartGUI();
 cartGUI.printCart(shoppingCart);   // Now it will allow you to use the same cart instance every time
```